# Updating all packages in GHC global package db to latest versions

Tags: haskell, ghc

I am trying to install the latest versions of all the Hackage packages that I use, and I would like to update the packages that ship with GHC 7.6.3 (except maybe for the base package) to their latest versions.

Is there an easy way to do this?

If there is not an easy way to update all the packages in GHC's global package db, is there an easy way to update the [time] package in the global package db to the latest version?

Regards
--Rouan

Comment: Looking at the information you get from cabal upgrade (deprecated command but gives a nice guide on what you should do instead) can be a good start.

Comment: I know this is not an answer: However, I don't think what you want is really a good idea. Quite often, other packages are tested with the current Haskell platform, not the latest versions of the "core" packages. Furthermore, some packages that can't be upgraded (the `ghc` library, for example) have other core packages as dependencies, so upgrading core packages will lead to problems in applications depending on one of the non-upgradeable packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find a reliable, easy way to update all the core packages that ship with GHC, so I just updated all the non-core packages, and will wait for the new release of GHC to include updates to the core packages.